# How to show the line number from the file invoking the logger, not the logger file itself?

Tags: python, logging, logfile, python-logging

I have a custom logging class, which has the following format:

```
log_format = "%(asctime)s.%(msecs)d %(levelname)-8s [%(processName)s] [%(threadName)s] %(filename)s:%(lineno)d --- %(message)s"
```

My project tree looks something like this:

```
.
├── exceptions.py
├── logger.py
├── settings.py
└── main.py
```

In main.py I import my custom `Logger` from `logger.py`. On several places I perform logging using the following syntax:

`Logger.info("Transcribed audio successfully.")`

However when looking at the logs, the `filename` and `lineno` params are always referring to my `Logger` class, not the actual function from `main.py` which invoked the logging:

```
2023-02-15 10:48:06,241.241 INFO     [MainProcess] [MainThread] logger.py:38 --- Transcribed audio successfully.
```

Is there a way to change this? I would like that the log entry states something like:

```
2023-02-15 10:48:06,241.241 INFO     [MainProcess] [MainThread] main.py:98 --- Transcribed audio successfully.
```

---

This is my `logger.py` file:

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler


class Logger:
    log_format = "%(asctime)s.%(msecs)d %(levelname)-8s [%(processName)s] [%(threadName)s] %(filename)s:%(lineno)d --- %(message)s"

    @staticmethod
    def setup_single_logger(name, logfile, level):
        handler = RotatingFileHandler(logfile, mode='a', maxBytes=1024 * 1024, backupCount=10)
        handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(Logger.log_format))
        logger = logging.getLogger(name)
        logger.setLevel(level)
        logger.addHandler(handler)
        return logger

    @staticmethod
    def setup_logging():
        Logger.info_logger = Logger.setup_single_logger('INFO', '/path/to/your/logfile.log', logging.INFO)

    @staticmethod
    def info(msg, *args, **kwargs):
        Logger.info_logger.info(msg, *args, **kwargs)


Logger.setup_logging()
```

And an example `main.py` is:

```py
from logger import Logger

Logger.info("Transcribed audio successfully.")
```

Comment: Well this is a  strange way to set your logging, but as I suspected, you are creating the logger object in `Logger`. The line `logger = logging.getLogger(name)` should be ***in main***. You should only do the setup in `logger.py`

Comment: Are you familiar with the https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html ?

Comment: I've definitely looked at the cookbook, but I do agree. The logging is a little strange, but it had to be done this way to accommodate some other constraints. Keep in mind I've omitted a lot of code from the Logger, this is just a basic setup.

Comment: If I understood correctly, I should create the logger in the main file? This is a problem for me since I'm also redirecting logs from my backend Gunicorn (flask) application as well as an AI model being used under the hood.

Comment: I can imagine. But the bottom line is where the `.info` call is done. In your case that's the line `Logger.info_logger.info(msg, *args, **kwargs)` which I imagine is what you always see in the logs. You need to have a local `logger` in main and do the `.info` calls on that. You might want to change the logic to pass the `logger` object from main to `Logger` to do the rest of the setup. Or do `basicConfig` in `Logger` and just pull the `logger` in main

Comment: Well it sounds like your setup is more complicated, but still, if I understand your worry - it's not a problem! The first line of the cookbook mentions *"Multiple calls to `logging.getLogger('someLogger')` __return a reference to the same logger object__. This is true not only within the same module, but __also across modules__ as long as it is in the same Python interpreter process."* (emphasis mine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you setup ***and create*** your logger in `logging.py`. So when you call `Logger.info` from main, the actual call of `info` on the logger object is done inside `logger.py`. You just created an interface for yourself to the logger object, but the underlying call is still the one specifying the attributes of the message.

What you could do is leave only the ***setup*** in `logger.py`, and let `main.py` have its own logger ***object***.

So `log.py` (changed name due to clashes) can be:

```py
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

def basic_config():
    log_format = "%(asctime)s.%(msecs)d %(levelname)-8s [%(processName)s] [%(threadName)s] %(filename)s:%(lineno)d --- %(message)s"

    handler = RotatingFileHandler('logfile.log', mode='a', maxBytes=1024 * 1024, backupCount=10)
    handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(log_format))

    logging.basicConfig(handlers=(handler,), level=logging.INFO)
```

(I felt like the use of the class was not necessary)

And `main.py`:

```py
import log
import logging

log.basic_config()
logger = logging.getLogger(__file__)

logger.info("test")
```

Now the log file I got from running once with your code and once with mine was:

```
2023-02-15 13:14:30,275.275 INFO     [MainProcess] [MainThread] log.py:23 --- test
2023-02-15 13:18:51,358.358 INFO     [MainProcess] [MainThread] main.py:7 --- test
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Combining this answer, some googling and referencing the cookbook again I managed to solve my problem. I would highlight that the most helpful aspect is that the command which calls logger.info is the one which is considered to be the "linenumber" in the logs. Therefore wrapping those calls around other functions was a bad idea.

Comment: @waykiki yes exactly. That indeed was my point. I forgot to mention that I don't believe you can bypass that also. i.e. there is no argument or some workaround you can do to change the linenumber being sent to the message this way. The only way (I know and can think of) is to have the actual `info` call from the source. Glad I could help in any way :)